IAM Authentication failed to aws DocumentDB
As IAM authentication for documentdb has been announced here 
So following the AWS DocumentDB guide here, I created an IAM user with the following command:
db.createUser(
    {
        user: "arn:aws:iam::<account_id>:user/iam_test_user",
        mechanisms: ["MONGODB-AWS"],
        roles: [ { role: "readWrite", db: "twitter" } ]
    }
);

I granted the user AmazonDocDBFullAccess and AmazonDocDBElasticFullAccess permissions.
Additionally, I generated an access key and secret access key for the user through the AWS console. When attempting to connect using mongosh with the command below, I encounter an authentication error:
mongosh --host 'aws-documentdb-iam-auth.cluster-<random_string>.us-east-1.docdb.amazonaws.com' --port 27017 -u '<access_key>' -p '<access_key_secret>' --authenticationDatabase '$external' --authenticationMechanism 'MONGODB-AWS'

Note: TLS is disabled for testing purposes, but the same error occurs with TLS enabled. Mongosh inputs are URL encoded.
Can anyone help me troubleshoot this authentication issue?
I have followed the documentdb IAM auth guide, but iam auth not working.
I am expecting to authenticate aws documentdb using iam auth.

As per AWS, Mongo Compass do not support correct NodeJs driver.
Drivers that support Amazon DocumentDB 5.0 and the MONGODB-AWS authentication mechanism should work with the IAM authentication implementation in Amazon DocumentDB. There is a known limitation with NodeJS drivers which are currently not supported by Amazon DocumentDB for IAM authentication. NodeJS driver support will be updated once the limitation is resolved

Please include a reference to the information providing.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
